# What do people say "hard and soft palate" in everyday conversations?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

My son ate bread and the bread happened to stick to the "hard and soft palate" of his mouth.

I had to put my fingers in to "**take it off**".

**What do people say "*hard and soft palate*" in everyday conversations?**

For example, "**the bread got stuck on her inner upper mouth and I had to take it off with my fingers**"

Comment: Next time, give the child a glass of water or milk to loosen the sticky dry mass. Anyway, it's probably better to say "remove" the bread.

Comment: If it was your son, it was **his** mouth, not 'hers'!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual expression is "the roof of one's mouth" and "the back of one's throat". Ordinary conversation wouldn't make fine anatomical distinctions.